# Angular UI Grid show encoded data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-grid

Is there a way to display data in format

```
"{\"brand\":\"newBrand\",\"Id\":\"1\",\"field\":\"1\",\"date\":1437487498449,\"period\":2,\"newUser\":0}"
```

to show them separately (every piece of data in appropriate column - column1 - Id, column2 - brand etc.) in the table(single row)?

I parse (JSON.parse) the data, but I cannot separate them and show in appropriate column - all data go to first column.

I'm trying to reproduce [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mNGfA45l0pTui6ytxIRE?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI-Grid takes an array of objects as data, so you need to contain your json in an array. Just add brackets around your parsed json object.

```
  $scope.myData = [JSON.parse("{\"brand\":\"newBrand\",\"Id\":\"1\",\"field\":\"1\",\"date\":1437487498449,\"period\":2,\"newUser\":0}")];
```

Same holds for multiple json objects:

```
  $scope.myData = [
    JSON.parse("{\"brand\":\"newBrand\",\"Id\":\"1\",\"field\":\"1\",\"date\":1437487498449,\"period\":2,\"newUser\":0}"),
    JSON.parse("{\"brand\":\"newBrand\",\"Id\":\"1\",\"field\":\"1\",\"date\":1437487498449,\"period\":2,\"newUser\":0}")
  ];
```